# Increment/decrement buttons on category page without refeshing

Tags: magento2.3, addtocart, quantity

I want to add increment and decrement buttons for quantity on catalog page without refreshing the page
 Pease help!

Answer (score 0):

```
create a block
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;

class ProductsList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList
{

}
Then add preference in di.xml file as follows
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductsList" />
</config>
"Then add in templates folder as product/widget/content/grid.phtml"
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
/** @var \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList $block */
$helper = $this->helper('vendor\module\Helper\Data');
// var_dump($helper->getDropDownCategory());
// var_dump($helper->getCurrentCategory()); ?>
<?php $helper = $this->helper('vendor\module\Helper\Data'); ?>
<?php if ($exist = ($block->getProductCollection() && $block->getProductCollection()->getSize())) : ?>
    <?php
    $type = 'widget-product-grid';
    $mode = 'grid';
    $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
    $items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();

    $showWishlist = true;
    $showCompare = true;
    $showCart = true;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    $description = false;
    ?>
    <div class="block widget block-products-list <?= $mode ?>">
        <?php if ($block->getTitle()) : ?>
            <div class="block-title">
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($block->getTitle())) ?></strong>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <div class="block-content">
            <?= '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
            <div class="products-<?= $mode ?> <?= $mode ?>">
                <ol class="product-items <?= $type ?>">
                    <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($items as $_item) : ?>
                        <?= ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="product-item">' : '</li><li class="product-item">' ?>
                        <div class="product-item-info">
                            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>" class="product-item-photo">
                                <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="product-item-details">
                                <strong class="product-item-name">
                                    <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>"
                                       class="product-item-link">
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
                                    </a>
                                </strong>
                                <?php if ($templateType) : ?>
                                    <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml($_item, $type) ?>
                                <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_item) ?>
                                <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare || $showCart) : ?>
                                    <div class="product-item-inner">
                                        <div class="product-item-actions">
                                            <?php if($showCart) : ?>
                                            <?php if($helper->isEnabled()):?>                
                                            <?php if(($helper->pageType()) && ($helper->productType($_item->getId())) ):?>
                                            <?php if(in_array($helper->getCurrentCategory(), $helper->getDropDownCategory()) ):?>
                                            <div class="box-tocart">
                                            <div class="fieldset">
                                            <?php $id = $_item->getId(); ?>
                                                <?php //if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
                                                <div class="field qty">
                                                    <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                                                    <div class="control">
                                                    <span class="minus"><button type="button" style="background-color:#<?= $helper->buttonColor();?>;color:#<?= $helper->signColor();?>;" onclick="
                                                    var result = document.getElementById('<?= $id ?>');
                                                    var qty = result.value;
                                                    if( !isNaN( qty ) && qty > 1 ) result.value--;
                                                    return false;">-</button>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <input type="number"
                                                            name="qty"
                                                            id="<?= $id ?>"
                                                            value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                                                            title="<?php echo __('Qty') ?>"
                                                            class="input-text qty"
                                                            data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                                                            readonly/>
                                                    <span class="plus"><button type="button" style="background-color:#<?= $helper->buttonColor();?>;color:#<?= $helper->signColor();?>;" onclick="
                                                    var result = document.getElementById('<?= $id ?>');
                                                    var qty = result.value;
                                                    if( !isNaN( qty )) result.value++;
                                                    return false;">+</button>
                                                    </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <?php //endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                <div class="actions-primary">
                                                    <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_item); ?>
                                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>" method="post">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($postParams['data']['product']) ?>">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="<?= Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?= $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
                                                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                            <button type="submit"
                                                                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                                    class="action tocart primary">
                                                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                            </button>
                                                        </form>
                                                    <?php else : ?>
                                                        <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()) : ?>
                                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                        <?php else : ?>
                                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare) : ?>
                                                <div class="actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                                    <?php if ($this->helper(\Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data::class)->isAllow() && $showWishlist) : ?>
                                                        <a href="#"
                                                           data-post='<?= $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_item) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Wish List')) ?>">
                                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php if ($block->getAddToCompareUrl() && $showCompare) : ?>
                                                        <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare::class);?>
                                                        <a href="#" class="action tocompare" data-post='<?= $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_item) ?>' title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Compare')) ?>">
                                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')) ?></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?= ($iterator == count($items) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Then make a file in templates folder as product/widget/content/grid.phtml and add code to this to add button

Comment: I did all the steps but nothing changes on category page. Please help

Comment: I have done this for me recently and it works correctly

Comment: You did this for product listing page?

Comment: I did this for all pages and categories

Comment: What did u put on ProductsList.php please?

Comment: check this above phtml code

Answer (score 0):

for listing page

```
<?php 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action; 
?>
<?php 
$helper = $this->helper('FME\ProductQtyIncrementDecrementButton\Helper\Data');
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $block->getData('outputHelper'); 
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()):?>
    <div class="message info empty">
    <div><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('We can\'t find products matching the selection.')) ?></div>
    </div>
<?php else:?>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?= $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?= $viewMode ?> products-<?= $viewMode ?>">
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):?>
            <li class="item product product-item">
                <div class="product-item-info"
                     id="product-item-info_<?= $_product->getId() ?>"
                     data-container="product-<?= $viewMode ?>">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = 'left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                       class="product photo product-item-photo"
                       tabindex="-1">
                        <?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <?php
                            $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                        ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
                                <?= $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                        <?= $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()):?>
                            <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                            <?php if($helper->isEnabled()):?>
                            <?php if(($helper->pageType()) && ($helper->productType($_product->getId()))) : ?>
                                <?php if(in_array($helper->getCurrentCategory(), $helper->getDropDownCategory()) ):?>
                            <div class="box-tocart">
                            <div class="field qty">
                            <?php $id = "qty_".$_product->getId(); ?>
                                <label class="label" for="<?= $id ?>"><span><?php echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                                <div class="control">
                                <span class="minus"><button type="button" style="background-color:#<?= $helper->buttonColor();?>;color:#<?= $helper->signColor();?>;"
                                onclick="
                                var result = document.getElementById('<?= $id ?>');
                                var qty = result.value;
                                // alert(qty);
                                if( !isNaN( qty ) && qty > 1 )
                                document.getElementById('<?= $id.'qty'?>').value = Number(--result.value);
                                return false;">-</button>
                                </span>
                                <input type="number"
                                    name="qty"
                                    id="<?= $id ?>"
                                    value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                                    class="input-text qty"
                                    title="<?= __('Qty') ?>"
                                    data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                                    />
                                <span class="plus"><button type="button" style="background-color:#<?= $helper->buttonColor();?>;color:#<?= $helper->signColor();?>;"
                                onclick="
                                alert(JSON.parse(<?= json_encode($helper->changeQtyStep());?>));
                                var result = document.getElementById('<?= $id ?>');
                                var qty = result.value;
                                if( !isNaN( qty )) 
                                document.getElementById('<?= $id.'qty'?>').value = Number(++result.value);
                                return false;">+</button>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                                <div class="actions-primary">
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()):?>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <?php $id = "qty_".$_product->getId(); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                              data-product-sku="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                                              action="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>"
                                              method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                   name="product"
                                                   value="<?= $postParams['data']['product'] ?>"
                                                   >
                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                    id="<?= $id.'qty'?>"
                                                   name="qty"
                                                   value="qty"
                                                   >
                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                   name="<?= Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>"
                                                   value="<?=
                                                   $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>"
                                                    >
                                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                    title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                    class="action tocart primary">
                                                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    <?php else:?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()):?>
                                            <div class="stock available">
                                                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                        <?php else:?>
                                            <div class="stock unavailable">
                                                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ?
                                    $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                                        $position,
                                        'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.actions-primary'
                                    ) : '' ?>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary">
                                    <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')):?>
                                        <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ?
                                    $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                                        $position,
                                        'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.actions-secondary'
                                    ) : '' ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($showDescription):?>
                                <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                    <?= $_helper->productAttribute(
                                        $_product,
                                        $_product->getShortDescription(),
                                        'short_description'
                                    ) ?>
                                    <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                                       title="<?= $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                       class="action more"><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Learn More')) ?></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ?
                $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                    $position,
                    'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.product-item-actions'
                ) : '' ?>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()):?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "<?= $escaper->escapeJs($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
        <?php endif; ?>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where should I put this code please?

Comment: in your phtml file